# How to manually close a websocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

If I'm not using a context for a websocket, how would I manually close it? When I try running conn.close() I get an `event loop is closed` error. Here is what I have so far:

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import websockets

# connect -- works OK
conn = async_to_sync(websockets.connect)("ws://localhost:8000/ws/registration/123/")

# send message -- works OK
async_to_sync(conn.send)("hello")

# disconnect -- doesn't work
async_to_sync(conn.close)()
```

What should the last part of this be?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `websockets.create_connection` ?

Comment: @madjaoue no -- I'm very new to this websockets library, so any suggestions would be great! -- also, I don't see that in the methods supported: `  'client', 'compatibility', 'connect', 'exceptions' `

Comment: which version do you use for python ? and websocket-client ?

Comment: I never used websockets library, but I use [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) on a daily basis and it seems to do the job very well. You can create a connection `ws = create_connection(someWsUrl)`, and then you can use `ws.send`, `ws.recv`, or `ws.close`. I can put a little exmaple. On the installation side, `pip install websocket-client`, and finally to import the module : `from websocket import create_connection`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @madjaoue -- wow thanks for that tip. I've switched over to that library and it makes things 100x easier and more straightforward.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) library, it's already sync and pretty straightforward.

**Install**

`pip install websocket-client`

**Usage**

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection(someWsUrl)  # open socket
ws.send(someMessage)  # send to socket
ws.recv(nBytes)  # receive from socket
ws.close()  # close socket
```